# Virtualbox guest OS installation from exe

Tags: virtualbox

I know installing guest OS such as Kali with its "iso" file in Virtualbox. But now I have an exe installation file for another candidate guest OS and I don't know how I can install this OS into virtual box due to its extension. How can I install the guest OS from exe file in Virtualbox, not iso file?

Answer (score 0):

Installing .exe is possible only under Windows OS. So you would have to install an OS in order to run the OS installer.